# I thought react-spring (useSpring) causes the component to re-render a lot, but it may not and how do we make it so?

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I thought react-spring `useSpring()` causes the component to re-render a lot, so if it is a component that already has a lot of CPU intensively work to do, then react-spring is not best suited for the task.

I can see that it re-renders a lot, in their example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dew-9tfi9?file=/src/App.tsx

(by looking at the console.log output, which has a lot of print out of `renderCount`.  The print out is a lot more when we change the duration to `5000` which is 5 seconds).

Likewise, if it is a component that is similar to react-spring, it'd render a lot:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-currying-9pheq

However, the following code:

```
let renderCount = 0

export default function App() {
  const styles = useSpring({
    loop: true,
    to: [
      { opacity: 1, color: '#ffaaee' },
      { opacity: 0.5, color: 'rgb(14,26,19)' },
      { transform: 'translateX(100px)' },
      { transform: 'translateX(0px)' },
    ],
    from: { opacity: 0, color: 'red', transform: 'translateX(0px)' },
    config: { duration: 500 },
  })

  console.log('renderCount', ++renderCount)

  return <a.div style={styles}>I will fade in and out</a.div>
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-rgb-j2bx3?file=/src/App.tsx

We can see that the `renderCount` hardly get printed out at all.  `react-spring` should need to keep on updating the `style` of the component, so after a minute, I'd expect a lot of print out of `renderCount` like the first two examples above, but it does not.

How and why doesn't react-spring cause a lot of re-rendering in this case, and how do we know in what situation would react-spring cause a lot of re-rendering (and how to prevent it)?

Answer (score 5):

`react-spring` updates styles incrementally to create animations (as opposed to css animations with `transition`).

### Naive animations outside React

If `react-spring` was to exist outside of React (which it OBVIOUSLY doesn't because then it wouldn't be named `react-spring`), this could most easily be done by modifying a given element's style by means of Javascript according to some predetermined pattern based on multiple factors (like delay, duration, etc....). One scenario could be

```
...
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("#el").style.opacity = 0.34,100)
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("#el").style.opacity = 0.39,150)
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("#el").style.opacity = 0.42,200)
...
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("#el").style.opacity = 1.0, 1000)
```

Exactly how this would be implemented is of course not the point of this answer and the above would be a very naive implementation, but this is basically what could go on if we wanted to make some animated transition where the interpolation between two endpoints would be calculated and implemented by ourselves (using spring physics) as opposed to in the browser (with css `transition`).

### Naive animations in React

In React, we know that the preferred way to do things is to provide changes inside React, which React then processes after which necessary changes to the DOM is handled by React. Taking the previous (naive) example to React, this would imply some scheme where a state storing the `opacity` would be updated repeatedly until the desired endpoint was reached.

```
const Component = () => {
    ...
    const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        ...
        setTimeout(() => setOpacity(0.34),100)
        setTimeout(() => setOpacity(0.39),150)
        setTimeout(() => setOpacity(0.42),200)
        ...
        setTimeout(() => setOpacity(1.0), 1000)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div style={{ opacity }} ... />
    )
}
```

This would work, but as one would expect, it could be quite burdensome since animations are supposed to happen fast and smooth and React rerendering on every animation frame could be problematic; if the component within which animation took place was expensive to render, the animation itself could be suffering and not look very good.

### `react-spring` in React

The solution to this problem by `react-spring` is to do updates OUTSIDE of React via refs instead. The previous toy example could look like:

```
const Component = () => {
    ...
    const ref = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if(ref.current) {
            ...
            setTimeout(() => ref.current.style.opacity = 0.34,100)
            setTimeout(() => ref.current.style.opacity = 0.39,150)
            setTimeout(() => ref.current.style.opacity = 0.42,200)
            ...
            setTimeout(() => ref.current.style.opacity = 1.0, 1000)
        }
    }, [])
    ...
    return (
        <div ref={ref} ... />
    )
}
```

Again, this is an **example**, exactly how one would implement this in the best way (as in `react-spring`) is a different story. But we can agree on that if we would log to the console every time the above component rendered, it would only log once even though the opacity would continue to change.

To sum up, when `react-spring` is used optimally, it uses refs to update properties on DOM elements whereupon React is by-passed. Thanks to this, a component may render only once but still make repeated animations. This particularly applies to the situation when the api is used to perform updates (as oppose to storing a state in a parent component which is set every time we want an animation to take place):

```
const [spring, api] = useSpring(() => ({ <INITIAL PROPS> })) // use api to make changes
const spring = useSpring({ <INITIAL PROPS }) // rerender component to update props
```

When using the basic HTML elements supplied by `react-spring` (such as `animated.div`, `animated.span` etc...), `react-spring` takes care of attaching a ref on the corresponding DOM element and via this ref, it manages to animate the element and therefore also all the content in it. When creating your own custom component wrapped in `animated`, it is your concern to make sure that your custom component can take a ref (via `forwardRef`) and to pass it on to the element which should be animated, if you want optimal animations. If you don't do this, the element will be rerendered on every animation frame by `react-spring`. Even though this works too, it is suboptimal from a performance point of view.

### Your examples

In your examples some other things are at play as well. In the first example, the hook `useMeasure` is being used from `react-use-measure`. This hook will continuously provide different values from the child component (here height is provided) whereupon the parent will rerender. Since `Tree` components are nested, whenever ONE `Tree` component changes height, all parent `Tree` components whose heights will be changed will also rerender. We therefore see quite a lot of rerendering. Also, because `StrictMode` is enabled, the number is doubled. `useSpring` is used without api but it doesn't matter here since the parent rerenders a lot due to `useMeasure` anyways.

In your second example with `react-spring`, the api is not used either but since the animation is looped, it doesn't require any state in the parent to be set and so it doesn't rerender. Because the parent doesn't rerender, the `animated` component doesn't rerender either and so also in this case, it doesn't matter if we use the api or not. In this example if we would like to update the animated props however, using the api to do so would cause the parent NOT to rerender whereas otherwise, the state holding the props to update to would reside in the parent (or a grand-parent) and so the `animated` component would rerender as well when the parent rerenders.